# Modifying Cocos2D Sliding Menu Grid adding an extra BUY ME button

Tags: ios, menu, cocos2d-iphone, sliding

I am trying to use SlidingMenuGrid code inside my app and changing a bit the beahaviour. The thing is I am a bit stuck. In Brandon Reynolds's [blog](http://brandonreynolds.com/blog/2011/01/09/cocos2d-sliding-menu-grid/) you can find a sample project with the menu which is great. I am very greatful to him for sharing his useful code.

What I want to achieve is a sliding menu where not only the image item can be touched but also an image representing a button with the option to buy the product (or more buttons - example BUY/SELL - USE/STOP USING etc.. RPG Style). In the image below I used a menu item with text but in the final version I will want to use a Menu item with sprite.

SlidingMenuGrid works by accepting an array of CCMenuItemSprite and the API allows to set the display type, nr of columns and rows.

I have tried adding a CCMenu with a selector in the CCLayer where I also add the SlidingMenuGrid instance but unfortunately, even if I enable touches, the selector is never called when clicking on it.

I think that what is happening is that SlidingMenuGrid swallows all touches. I tried to modify it but I don't really understand the code and I was trying to find a simpler and easier solution (e.g. by adding a menu item on the Layer instead of playing with SlidingMenuGrid).

Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: That's what I want to achieve - more or less]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some previous users have mentioned that they have added a "Back" button to the system by placing it on another layer and setting the menugrid to not swallow touches. I have not tested this but I would think it should work..

[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+1 swallowsTouches:NO]

See the rest of the comments on the post on my blog for maybe some further information.

-Brandon Reynolds

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the super promt reply. It works perfectly. I spent one day on this and in 1 minute you solved it. I am really a beginner :)